# Python - mapping list of lists to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to make a correlation between a list of lists and a dictionay of lists.
On one hand, I have the following list:

```
list_1=[['new','address'],['hello'],['I','am','John']]
```

and on the other hand I have a dictionary of lists:

```
dict={'new':[1,3,4], 'address':[0,1,2], 'hello':[7,8,9], 'I':[1,1,1], 'John':[1,3,4]}
```

What I want to get is a new list of lists (of lists) like this:

```
list_2=[[[1,3,4],[0,1,2]],[[7,8,9]],[[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,3,4]]]
```

This means that every word from `list_1` was mapped to each value in the dictionary `dict` and what is more, notice that `'am'` from `list_1` that was not found in `dict` took values `[0,0,0]`.

Thanx in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just rebuild the list of lists using dictionary queries using `dict.get`, and a default value in case the key isn't found:

```
list_1=[['new','address'],['hello'],['I','am','John']]

d={'new':[1,3,4], 'address':[0,1,2], 'hello':[7,8,9], 'I':[1,1,1], 'John':[1,3,4]}

list_2=[[d.get(k,[0,0,0]) for k in sl] for sl in list_1]

print(list_2)
```

result:

```
[[[1, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2]], [[7, 8, 9]], [[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 3, 4]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_1=[['new','address'],['hello'],['I','am','John']]
dict={'new':[1,3,4], 'address':[0,1,2], 'hello':[7,8,9], 'I':[1,1,1], 'John':[1,3,4]}
list_2=[[dict[x] for x in l if x in dict] for l in list_1]
```

if you want a list even if the key doesn't exists in dict

```
list_2=[[dict.get(x, []) for x in l] for l in list_1]
```